# Website does not validate even after clarifying Facebook's Open Graph protocol

Tags: html, facebook-graph-api, w3c-validation

I followed the instructions at Facebook Developers Page, but this is still not validating.
Why is this?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
      xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta property="og:image" content="image.png" >
more meta
</head>
<html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `xmlns` property is only allowed in XHTML documents, you can't specify that in HTML. Try:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Also, it appears that even with the document type changed to XHTML, the `property` attribute is still not allowed on a `meta` element.

The following XHTML only produces the single error for the `property` attribute:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
  xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta property="og:image" content="image.png" />
<title>title</title>
</head>
<body>body</body>
</html>
```

**Edit:** I have found a document type that you can use that will pass at the W3C checker. It appears that this document type already uses XHTML 1.1 even though the title says 1.0 (not sure).

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-1.dtd">
```

Comment: Because the `property` attribute is never allowed on a `meta` in that case. I've updated my answer with another document type that will validate.